# How to change the text of the currently selected button inside an ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an ngFor loop going on some membership options. I would like to change the text inside the button from select to selected once the user chooses their options. The code i have now unfortunately changes all three buttons to selected when one has been clicked.

Typescript:

```
export class SelectPlanComponent implements OnInit {

  plans: any;
  selectedPlan?: Plan;
  buttonValue = "Select";

  constructor(private service: PlansService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getPlans()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.plans = response;
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  onSelect(plan: Plan): void {
    this.selectedPlan = plan;
    this.buttonValue = "Selected"
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="card" *ngFor="let plan of plans">
                <h2>{{plan.title}}</h2>
                <p >£{{plan.amount}}</p>
                <p>{{plan.duration}}</p>
                <div class="benefits-container">
                    <div class="benefits" *ngFor="let item of plan.description.items">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
                        </div>
                        <p>{{item}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="inverted-button" [class.selected]="plan === selectedPlan" (click)="onSelect(plan)">{{buttonValue}}</a>
            </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have one variable which is bound to all buttons. What you could do is the following

Checking if the selectedPlan is the plan for the current button

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let plan of plans">
                <h2>{{plan.title}}</h2>
                <p >£{{plan.amount}}</p>
                <p>{{plan.duration}}</p>
                <div class="benefits-container">
                    <div class="benefits" *ngFor="let item of plan.description.items">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
                        </div>
                        <p>{{item}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="inverted-button" [class.selected]="plan === selectedPlan" (click)="onSelect(plan)">{{plan === selectedPlan ? 'selected' : 'select' }}</a>
            </div>
```

and after that you can change your TypeScript Code as follows:

```
  onSelect(plan: Plan): void {
    this.selectedPlan = plan;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you both! Went with the bottom answer in the end! Very very helpful thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should create a property on the Plan object to keep track of whether it has been selected or not. Do this by modifying your Plan class to include a selected property, like this:

```
export class Plan {
  // existing properties go here

  selected: boolean;
}
```

Then, in your `onSelect()` method, you can set the selected property on the plan object to true when it is selected, like this:

```
onSelect(plan: Plan): void {
  this.selectedPlan = plan;
  plan.selected = true;
  this.buttonValue = "Selected";
}
```

In your HTML, you can use this selected property to conditionally render the "Selected" text on the button, like this:

```
<a class="inverted-button" [class.selected]="plan === selectedPlan" (click)="onSelect(plan)">
  {{ plan.selected ? "Selected" : "Select" }}
</a>
```